# Sum Program in Assembly Language

Tags: visual-studio, recursion, assembly, x86, masm

I have been trying to learn assembly language and I am still fairly new to it.

The task I am learning now is simple **recursion** and I am having some trouble with a task.

My Task to basically make this program below into Assembly language using Microsoft Visual Studio.

*I have made some progress but I have a few problems and I am stuck.*

Java program I am trying to replicate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=0, answer=0;              //line 7
        System.out.print("Enter positive integer: ");       //line 8
        n=keyboard.nextInt();               //line 9
         answer=sum(n);                 //line 10
         System.out.println("Sum is "+answer);      //line 11
}

public static int sum(int n)
{
       if (n==1) return 1;              //line 15
       else return n+sum(n-1);              //line 16
}
```

Here is the assembly program I have so far.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h
.STACK 4096

.DATA
n   DWORD   0
answer  DWORD   0
prompt1 BYTE    "Enter a positive integer",0
inputBuf    BYTE    20 DUP (?)
prompt2 BYTE    "Sum is ",0

.CODE
main PROC
    input   prompt1, inputBuf, 20   ;read characters coming in
    atod    inputBuf                ;convert to Integers
    mov n, eax                      ; n= eax (number input)
    push n                          ; 1st argument
    call sum                    ;sum(int n)
    add esp, 8                  ;remove parameter from stack

    dtoa    result, eax         ;convert
    output  prompt2, result     ;Sum label and result

    mov eax, 0
    ret
main ENDP

sum PROC
    push ebp        ;save location of caller's act record
    mov ebp, esp    ;establish a stack frame
    push eax        ;save register eax, used by sum
    
    cmp eax, 1
    je  L1          ;jump if n==1
    jne recursiveCase   ;jump to recursive case if n!=1

    pop ebx
    pop ebp
    ret

recursiveCase:
    mov eax, [ebp+8]        ;eax = n
    dec eax                 ;n-1
    call sum                ;recursive call sum(n-1)
    add esp 8
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]

END
```

Here are the main issues I am having:

1. Visual Studio is stating there is an error on Line 1 saying "Invalid character in file" code a2044. and I cannot find any solutions on how to fix this
2. I am having issue with my recursive algorithm and recalling the method and finally, sending the result value back
3. Adding the correct numbers to answer, such as the using esp and the length of the address

If anyone has any solutions or so example of what I am doing wrong this would be amazing.

Comment: I was able to fix the 1st issue that involved the io.h file i am importing. Now i just have trouble making the entirety of the program work

Comment: for what you establish a stack frame if you not use it ? for what you save `eax` register ? this is absolute senseless - because you need return result in this register. and this is "volatile" register, must not be preserved by function. you `push eax` but `pop ebx` . in `recursiveCase:` no `ret` .. parameters usually not passed in `eax` but in stack or first 2 in `ecx` and `edx`.. huge counts of error

Comment: and for what here recursion at all, when can do this in loop (much more effective) ?

Comment: @RbMm This chapter i am working on right now about using the stack and recursion. So the assignment task is to use recursion for the sum problem.

Comment: @RbMm  As i said I am still very new to recursion so I am defintely bound to have some errors

Comment: use next code for *sum* `@sum@4 proc
 jecxz @@0;
 push ecx;
 dec ecx;
 call @sum@4;
 pop ecx;
 add eax,ecx;
 ret;
@@0:
 mov eax,ecx;
 ret;
@sum@4 endp`

Comment: How is this relevant to C# or .NET?

Comment: and in c++ file can declare it as `extern "C" int __fastcall sum(int);` and simply call. I select `__fastcall` calling convention. and compare in *sum* not for 1 but for 0.